# git merge lock on Mac

Tags: git, emacs, merge

I'm doing the Merging lab in the git immersion tutorial. When I enter

```
$ git merge master
```

It takes me too

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

I cannot figure out how to complete the merge. I've tried `C - X`, and various commands like `:wq` which seem to work for `vi` text editor, but I believe I have `emacs` editor. The only command I know to get me out of the editor and back to the shell (I'm using bash) is `C - Z`, but that undoes the merge.

How can I save/complete the merge?

RESOLVED: based on suggestions below, switched to editor 'nano', with which I was able to complete merge. Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps you should configure an editor you know and like, first. :-)  Use `git config --global core.editor <name of editor>` to change the editor setup.

Comment: Any recommendations, between 'vi', 'nano', or something else? Very new to git and the shell..

Comment: I use vi (now vim) myself, but this is because it was the only suitable editor back in 1981.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using an editor that you're unfamiliar with. Consider changing it with

`git config --global core.editor nano`

or

`git config --global core.editor vim`

Documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Basic-Client-Configuration